# How to determine the variables used in a JAVA class when polymorphism is involved

Tags: java, dependencies, polymorphism, runtime

Here is the scenario. I have a class, called **BaseClass** and 6 class which extend this class: **DerivedClass1** to **DerivedCLass6**. BaseClass has, lets say, 500 variables and not all of them are needed for all of the DerivedClass[1..6]. Yes, this is really bad and that's what I am trying to fix.
The problem is that since polymorphism is used, after creating an instance of DerivedClass[1..6], it is assigned to a BaseClass reference. And every method call happens on this reference. So doing a "Find all references" is not very effective. Also, the code base is huge.

I need to figure out what common variables are used by these 6 derived classes and retain them in the BaseClass and move the remaining specific variables to their respective classes (the way it was supposed to be done to begin with).

Trying to manually trace each variable and figure out the control flow and logic is quite cumbersome. I was hoping someone had some better ideas.

--- UPDATE ---

I'll explain with an example.

```
public class BaseClass{

    private String common1;
    ...
    private String common6;

    private String var1;
    ...
    private String var60;
    // getters and setters follow
}

public class DerivedClass1 extends BaseClass{

    private String _1a;
    private String _1b;
    ...
    //getters and setters
}
```

...

```
public class DerivedClass6 extends BaseClass{

    private String _6a;
    private String _6b;
    ...
    //getters and setters
}
```

The BaseCLass variables common1 to common6 are used by all derived classes.

DerivedClass1 uses var1 to var10

DerivedClass2 uses var11 to var20

...

DerivedClass6 uses var51 to var60

What I want to do is figure out common1 to common6 and retain them in BaseClass.
And move the specific derived class variables to their respective classes. And these are POJO's, so there are no other methods apart from getters and setters.

The way these are used is the specific derived class object is created and assigned to base class reference. And methods are invoked on the base class reference. And the base class reference is used everywhere. In some situations, the object is retrieved from a hashmap based on an id and assigned to the base class reference. Even if I try to follow the code, I wont know what type of object is being used in that scenario.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Refactoring with an IDE will help.

Comment: what's your ide ? Perhaps it provides support for what you want to do, so we should know if it is Eclipse, IntelliJ, ... And telling us the version number would do no harm ;-)

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2. I am using the "Open Call Hierarchy" feature but I feel it isnt showing me all the references.

Comment: @markspace, refactor how?

Answer (score 0):

for each derived class:

```
javap -c Derived1.class >res
perl -n -e'/Field (.*):/ && print "$1\n"' <res | sort | uniq >derived1.list
```

This should give a list of all the fields which are accessed in this class

Then do:

```
javap Base.class | grep -v "(" | perl -n -e'/.* (.*);/ && print "$1\n"' | sort >base.list
```

This will give you the list of fields declared in the base class.

For each line in base.list, you can then check if you see it in only one of the derived.list files.

EDIT: 
Ok. I will reformulate your problem as follows, hopefully it captures what you mean:

1. a base class declares a number of private variables and accessors.
2. The class has a number of subclasses, each one calling some (but possibly not al) of the accessors in the superclass.
3. Those subclasses are instantiated by other classes and assigned to variables of type base class, and  methods which may refer to the superclass accessors  are called.

For each derived class you want to find the set of variables declared in the base class which are accessed (through accessors) only by such derived class, so you can move those variables in the dericed class itself.

First of all, point 3 is irrelevant: knowing that the derived class is accessed by other classes doesn't help.

I will use the following code as example:

```
class BaseClass{

    private String common1;
    private String common6;

    private String var1;
    private String var60;

    // getters and setters follow
    public String getCommon1() { return common1; }
    public String  getCommon6() { return common6; }
    public String getVar1() { return var1; }
    public String getVar60() { return var60; }

    public void setCommon1(String v) { common1 = v;}
    public void setCommon6(String v) { common6 = v;}
    public void setVar1(String v) { var1 = v;}
    public void setVar60(String v) { var60 = v;}

}

class DerivedClass1 extends BaseClass{

    private String _1a;
    private String _1b;

    //getters and setters
    public String get_1a() { return _1a; }
    public String get_1b() { return _1b; }

    public void foo() {
        setCommon1("val1");
        setCommon6("val6");
        setVar1("val1");
        System.out.println(getCommon1());
        System.out.println(getCommon6());
        System.out.println(getVar1());
        System.out.println(get_1a());
        System.out.println(get_1b());
    }
}

class DerivedClass2 extends BaseClass {
    //getters and setters

    public void foo() {
        setCommon1("val1");
        setCommon6("val6");
        setVar60("val60");
        System.out.println(getCommon1());
        System.out.println(getCommon6());
        System.out.println(getVar60());
    }
}
```

First, let's write a helper script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# find all variables accessed through accessors in the class
# passed as argument. Stor ethe list in <class-name>.accessed
# the names of vars are extracted from accessors invocations
# by stripping the initial set or get and lowercasing the first
# letter.
javap -c $1.class >$1.tmp1
perl -n -e'/Method [sg]et(.*):/ && print lcfirst("$1\n")' <$1.tmp1 | sort | uniq >$1.accessed

# find all the variables declared in the class passed as argument
javap -p $1.class >$1.tmp1
grep -v "(" <$1.tmp1 | perl -n -e'/.* (.*);/ && print "$1\n"' >$1.declared

# print only the variables which are accessed but do not appear in
# the variable declared
grep -x -v -f $1.declared $1.accessed
```

Save this script as `doit.sh`, and execute it on each derived class:

```
$ doit.sh DerivedClass1 >out1
$ doit.sh DerivedClass2 >out2

$ cat out1
common1
common6
var1

$ cat out2
common1
common6
var60
```

So, we got for each derived class the list of variables accessed through accessors which are declared in the base class.

you can find out variables appearing in both files with:

```
$ grep -x -f out1 out2 
common1
common6
```

These are the variables that have to stay in the base class.

Comment: I ran the first set of commands on the derived class and I got one variable which was referenced INSIDE this class. And this class has access to all the methods in the BaseClass, which are used to in various other classes (helper classes, delegates and so on). 

I think this problem can solved only at runtime. Some sort of code coverage might work.

Comment: This is the whole point. The first command will give you the list of all variables REFERENCED by the derived class, which may include vars in the class itself or on the superclass. The second command will give you the list of variable DECLARED in the class. By comparing the set of vars referenced in a derived class and those declared in the subclass you can find which variables belongong to the superclass the subclass referenced. Repeat the same for all subclasses and if a variable show up for more than a subclass, then you can't move it to a subclass

Comment: Right, I understand. In any other case it would work, but not in my case. The reason being the classes I am trying to refactor are POJO's. So in the derived class, there are no references to the BaseClass variables or methods. All the references are in other classes which create and use these POJO's. I think I should have provided sample code in the main question. Please let me know if you need me to. Thanks,

Comment: Not sure I follow. do you mean that other classes are referencing the variables in instances of the derived classes?

Comment: Yes, other classes where the business logic is implemented create an instance of the derived class pojo, which gets assigned to the base class reference. Then using seters and getters the values are assigned and retrieved. I updated the question with the example, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think your'e going to need a mix of automation and manual labor. Here's one approach:

First, get a list of all of the variables in `BaseClass`. Hopefully they're declared similarly and in one big chunk:

```
class BaseClass {
    protected int myInt;
    protected String myString = "default value";
    protected double myDouble;
    ...
```

If that's the case, you can just copy all of them into vim/emacs/whatever and do a bit of regex slinging to get the names. For instance, if they're all of the form `<protected|public> <type> <name> [= something];`, then you can run `:%s/ *\w\+ \+\w\+ \(\w\+\).*/\1/` in vim.

Now, given a name, we want to find all of the `.java` files that use it. This may yield some false positives, but hopefully not too many. This is pretty easy:

```
$ JAVA_FILES='First.java Second.java path/to/Third.java'
$ NEEDLE="myInt"
$ grep -l "\b${NEEDLE}\b" $JAVA_FILES | sort
```

Two notes:

- The `\b` bits look for word boundaries -- so the above will match `myInt = 1`, `int foo = myInt;` and `int len = myString.length() but not`myInteger = 123`or`sammyInt`.
- `$JAVA_FILES` is unquoted in the last line, because you want bash to expand these out into separate files (not treat them as one file with spaces in its name). This should be fine for code, since I doubt you have spaces in your package or class names. :)

Now it's a simple thing to write a loop. Let's say your var names are all in a file called `names.txt`:

```
JAVA_FILES='First.java Second.java path/to/Third.java'
for NEEDLE in $(cat names.txt); do
  printf '%s: ' "$NEEDLE"
  grep -l "\b${NEEDLE}\b" $JAVA_FILES | sort
done
```

And there you go: each line starts with the variable name, and then includes all of the Java classes that use it.

The process of actually using that information will be manual, but it should be pretty mechanical and straightforward.

Comment: I like the idea but I am not sure I am able to see the advantage of this over searching for the variables or even using the "Call Hierarchy" feature in the IDE. And the main problem is the manual part, which is what I am trying to do. Firstly, there are waaaay too many files. Secondly, well, lemme explain the scenario I came across: There was one method call which was retrieving the derived class object and assigning it to a base class reference FROM a hashmap! Using your approach or even the IDE, I can only find where the usage is. But I dont know which derived class object it is.

Comment: [continued] So static analysis won't get me far. I did have another idea. If I can add log messages in each of the getter methods and print out the object type, then I can run the app and test all use cases. Looking at the log file I should be able to figure out what derived type objects used what variables. But for reasons, I cant do this.